# Crontab mail issue

Tags: cron, email

I have `python script` which sends email by `shell function` "mail". It runs fine. However, when I put in crontab to run it is unable to send mail to the recipient, rather it sends error message to my address. Is there any issue that crontab cannot send mail running via another script?

Here is my crontab entry:

> 30 8 * * * /home/akand/./pyscript.py

The pyscript.py has

```
import os  
os.system(''' mail -s "Message" ...@gmail.com <<< "Please 
check ..." ''')
```

As I mentioned, `pyscript.py` runs fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the crontab entry that you are using.

Comment: Although I have edited tags, it doesn't show, at least not from my end.

Comment: You have an issue with your cron job and to see what the issue is, we would need to see what your crontab entry looks like. Please add the output of `crontab -l` (or just the specific entry) into the text of the question.

Comment: What's the error message? Is it an empty body or recipient? You may have an interactive environment variable that's not being set by cron.

Comment: In dead.letter following is produced:  To: found, not, command, line....@gmail.com
Subject: Message: ......
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Comment: When I send mail to the recipient directly from crontab works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeff mentioned, the environment variable was not passing. The command in crontab:

```
30 8 * * * $HOME/.bash_profile; /home/akand/./pyscript.py
```

worked.

Comment: I would have understood that it would work with `. "$HOME/.bash_profile"`, but as you have written it now, it just runs `.bash_profile` as a script. That means that the environment variables are _not_ passed on to the Python script.

Comment: If I understand well, the pyscript.py is in my home directory, that's the reason I do not need to specify  <. "$HOME/.bash_profile" >